# Is it okay to take logs of a sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I have a sequence $r_n^n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$, can I take logs of both sides and have

\begin{align}
n\log r_n &= \frac{n}{2}\log\left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)\\\\
\text{and so,}\\\\
\log r_n &=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}

The limit of $\log r_n$ is then clearly $0$ so $r_n \to 1$.

Is this allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $r_n$ are positive then this is fine, but it would be faster to just start by taking $n$th roots of both sides.

If some subsequence of the $r_n$ are negative for even $n$, then we cannot conclude that $r_n\to 1$.

Comment: Didn't even think of taking the $n^{th}$ root. Thanks for your answer anyway though!

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can pass limits through any continuous function. The logarithm is continuous, so you may take the limit of the log of a sequence and replace it with the log of the limit of the sequence. In particular the computation you performed is correct (but it is conceptually simpler to take the $n$th root of both sides). But in general just be careful that you don't take the logarithm of zero or negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, but this seems to be easier:
 $$r_n^n = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
 $$r_n = \sqrt{ 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$$
$$r_n \to 1$$